# Maven cxf-codegen-plugin generated source

Tags: maven, jaxb, cxf

I am using below Maven plugin to generate the JAXB classes for the given WSDL. It has generated the classes on `target\generated-sources` folder.

```
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
```

**My questions are:-**

1) Whether I need to maintain the classes generated under `src\main\java`. If yes, how to copy the files from generated source to destination?

I would like to consume the web service using the generated classes.

2) Should I commit the generated class files to source code repository (e.g. SVN, Git etc.)?

Comment: Usually you can just use the generated sources as they are: generated sources. You don't commit them and leave them under `target`. Your IDE should recognize them automatically as the `cxf-codegen-plugin` by default sticks to the Maven conventions for the target location.

Comment: You can provide the `<sourceRoot>src/main/java-generated</sourceRoot> ` under configuration. If can commit the generated sourceRoot if you don't want to generate it again and again. Also It will save others time for generating it again.